# C# Memory Mapped File - Bitmap

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

Can any help, please>

Can anyone provide me with the basics of passing (interprocess) a bitmap?

Send & Receive in C#

CreateFileMapping, I belive, is still the only way to do this.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this article is a little old but has some sample code that demonstrates it's usage.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446520.aspx

there are numerous other samples on MSDN as well as the web. Moving a biap this way won't be easy though, you'll have to save it to a MemoryStream first.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. In the end I managed to convert and old bit of c++ to C# for the MMF mechanism that I required. Using a file would have been too slow. It works as I need it to. Again, thaks all

Answer (score 0):

Are both applications written in .NET? If so, please take a look at WCF (Windows Communication Foundation).

See:
[IPC Mechanisms in C# - Usage and Best Practices..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121/ipc-mechanisms-in-c-usage-and-best-practices)

Comment: Many thanks all. Yes they are both .net, but have to be in .Net2 for the moment. In WCF there's a class that takes care of MMF in full. What a pain.