# How can I send data between two programs in C#?

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-3.0, remoting

I have two applications --> App1 and App2. App1 opens App2 by passsing some command line arguments using System.Diagnostic.Process(). The user now accesses App2.

However, when the user changes some command arguments in App1, I need to open the existing aplication (App2) without closing it using the new parameters.

How can I do this?

Any feedback would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not trying to be smart or rude, but punctuation is your friend. See in the last statement I used an apostraphy, a comma and a full stop to help clarify what I am saying. People are more willing to help when they don't have to spend time working out what you are asking.

Comment: yes, punctuation IS your friend, and not to be rude, but not everyone is speaking English as their first language.

Comment: You should try updating your question title, say something like "How can I send parameters between two programs in C#?" It'd be a lot more help to people seeing your question to know what it was about.

Comment: Considering that Remoting is deprecated, why add that tag?

Comment: @Muad'Dib (or should I call you Paul?): Good point, but to me it read more like the halting English used by the Text Speak Generation, rather than the halting English of a foreign language speaker. That was just my impression. Apologies for any offence caused folks.

Comment: John is remoting marked as deprecated - I don't think it is?  Sure you may prefer to use WCF, but I'm pretty sure that remoting is still supporting in all versions of the framework.

Comment: @Binary Worrier -- No worries, mate.  Sometimes people forget the first W in "www" and, being married to an ESL, I tend to be a little more aware of the situation then most.

Answer (score 5):

Another option might be a WCF based solution.
See [WCF Chat Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb690929.aspx)

Comment: +1 because on the current version of .Net, WCF is the choice when doing IPC.

Answer (score 4):

You should use IPC. See [IPC Mechanisms in C# - Usage and Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121/ipc-mechanisms-in-c-usage-and-best-practices) for some useful links.

Comment: Technically, you're restating the original question because IPC *is* communication between two different processes. By your link, it's clear you're referring to IPC with WCF, which is a good solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why not plain old TCP/IP using sockets (client and server).

Answer (score 0):

What your looking to do is not straight forward. The pre-packaged way to do it in .net is called [Remoting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Remoting), it's built into the framework and allows IPC (Interprocess calls).

Depending on your level of experience, you may be better rolling your own simplified version of this. e.g. Have the two programs pass data using files.

App1 writes parameters to a text file (XML, Delimited, your choice really).

Have a timer on App2 that wakes up every 10th of a second and checks to see if there is a new parameter file. If so it consumes it and delets the file.

**UPDATE**
As correctly pointed our by John Saunders, Remoting has been superseeded by [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation), however there is still lots of information out there on Remoting and it might not be a bad place to get started.

Comment: Actually, remoting has been deprecated in favor of WCF.

Comment: @John: Yes, I seem to remember that being announced. Why am I never invited to these meetings where these decisions are made? It might be an oversight by some overworked Microsoft minion, or some day soon all those old, out of date invitations will find me and come flooding into my mail box . . . any day now . . .

Comment: WCF has a somewhat steeper learning curve, I believe, but the desired protocol looks pretty simple and there should be good sample code out there for similarly simple communication.

Comment: @Greg: simple use of WCF is very easy - just some terminology differences.

Comment: @Binary: I cannot locate the statement about Remoting being deprecated. It's pretty obvious, though. Once most of your functionality has been replaced, there's not much room left.

Comment: @Binary: found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72x4h507.aspx: "This topic is specific to a legacy technology that is retained for backward compatibility with existing applications and is not recommended for new development. Distributed applications should now be developed using the  Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)."

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [`WindowsFormsApplicationBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.aspx) class (from `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly) with the following code in my`Program.cs` file:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;

namespace TestSolution
{
    sealed class Program : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] commandLine)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            var program = new Program()
            {
                IsSingleInstance = Properties.Settings.Default.IsSingleInstance
            };

            // Here you can perform whatever you want to perform in the second instance

            // After Program.Run the control will be passed to the first instance    
            program.Run(commandLine);
        }

        protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
        {
            MainForm = new ImportForm();
        }

        protected override bool OnStartupNextInstance(StartupNextInstanceEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            // This code will run in the first instance

            return base.OnStartupNextInstance(eventArgs);
        }
    }
}
```