# Command line and exe's

Tags: c#, command-line, exe

I've found code examples where one is opening an exe from C#, and passing in args, but after it's launched, how do we keep interacting with it, like send in commands and get a response back?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IPC Mechanisms in C# - Usage and Best Practices..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121/ipc-mechanisms-in-c-usage-and-best-practices)

Comment: How do you want to get the response back? To display or ??

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to achieve *inter-process communication* (IPC). I've actually found some [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121/ipc-mechanisms-in-c-usage-and-best-practices).

Comment: I was almost thinking WCF could be a choice but wasn't sure how to use it in this context. I'll do some reading on IPC. THanks much

Comment: Well, I decided to just create a C++ wrapper dll for the C++ console app, and simply call the wrapper from my WPF app. All is good. Thanks much for the tips though on the IPC.