# Comunication between 2 processes using messages

Tags: c#, ipc, wndproc, single-instance

Started [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508622/how-to-send-object-instances-to-wndproc) but still the question not closed - I think that I need to revise the whole architecture - so please give your opinions...

Here is the how the application should work: 
An scheduler executes multiple time the same application, but with different arguments.
If the application is started without any parameter or argument - it shows an form which will allows to edit some config data.
Despite of multiple executions there should be only one instance of application.

My approach - for single-instance I've used Mutex with ApplicationContext and NativeWindow. This is described [here](http://www.diy-wiki.com/Programming%20Dot%20Net.TrayAppCSharp.ashx)
The thing that I can't overcome - when an new instance of application is started- if this instance is started with parameters - how to send data - the parameters - to the application's instance that is running?
I've tried to send data using messages - SendMessage/PostMessage - but didn't succeed.

Maybe someone could give another approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917883/c-how-to-single-instance-application-that-accepts-new-parameters, the link to the blog is dead but in the comments is a link to archive.org. Go and get it there.

Comment: using SendMessage works.