# Contact a windows app / service from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, .net-remoting

I've got a windows application that is multi threaded and processes jobs for me. I want to call this application from asp.net / c# in the code behind and wait for a response. Could you advise what the best approach would be to do this? I've been reading about WCF, WF and .net remoting but I'm a bit confused as to which to use. I'm happy to change the windows application to something else as long as it can still be multi threaded.

Thanks,
Colin

Answer (score 1):

.NET Remoting under performs compared to WCF, WF is for other things...

you could use probably any kind of IPC system, WCF is a good alternative, see here:

[IPC Mechanisms in C# - Usage and Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121/ipc-mechanisms-in-c-usage-and-best-practices)

Comment: Agreed.  I would use WCF, it sounds like this is what your looking for.