# internal communication between a .net and C++ application

Tags: c#, .net, c++

I see there are some other posts related to this issue. However, I want to ask if there is new elegant way to just exchange some messages between a C#.net application and a C++ application?

They are running on the same machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming your looking to do interprocess communication, check out this article on using NamedPipes: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/dotnetnamedpipespart1.aspx

Comment: this one is for two .net applications, right? I am looking for a solution between a C++ app and a .net app

Comment: Named pipes are built into the OS and can be used to communicate between processes regardless of the language they are built with. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: named pipes deserve more love. They are ubiquitous in the Unix world, but windows programmers prefer, say, DCOM or whatever. Named pipes take a couple of LOC to get working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many mechanisms you can use to do this.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) enumerates the common ways to accomplish interprocess communication on the windows platform. Most if not all are possible form both C# and C++ (though I would hate to see you use DDE from C#, though [it has apparently been done](http://ndde.codeplex.com/)).

Comment: in addition, I found this post helpful as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121/ipc-mechanisms-in-c-sharp-usage-and-best-practices

Answer (score 3):

What you want is inter-process communication (IPC), which is language-agnostic by definition.

Typical solutions include:

- Named pipes (also called FIFOs)
- Mail slots
- File mapping
- Sockets
- RPC
- etc.

You use different ones depending on your needs.

Here is information on windows-supported IPC methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Most of this functionality is exposed in C# through WCF, which is windows-specific of course. If you're using Mono, you're out of luck.

C++ doesn't define any IPC constructs in the language itself, so you will have to use platform-specific libraries regardless.

Search around for IPC examples in C# and C++ and you will get plenty of hits.

Here's a SO post to get you started: [IPC Mechanisms in C# - Usage and Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121/ipc-mechanisms-in-c-sharp-usage-and-best-practices)

Answer (score 1):

I have always used sockets, that is the simplest way I can think of (not the most elegant though)