# Only one program at a time

Tags: c#, concurrency, semaphore

I have a situation where I need to have only one instance of a program running at the same time.

This would be trivial like this:

```
class OneAtATimePlease
{
  static void Main()
  {
    // Naming a Mutex makes it available computer-wide. Use a name that's
    // unique to your company and application (e.g., include your URL).

    using (var mutex = new Mutex (false, "oreilly.com OneAtATimeDemo"))
    {
      // Wait a few seconds if contended, in case another instance
      // of the program is still in the process of shutting down.

      if (!mutex.WaitOne (TimeSpan.FromSeconds (3), false))
      {
        Console.WriteLine ("Another app instance is running. Bye!");
        return;
      }
      RunProgram();
    }
  }

  static void RunProgram()
  {
    Console.WriteLine ("Running. Press Enter to exit");
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Except for the small detail, that I need the EXISTING process to terminate, not the new one.

I tried making a semaphore the existing process could listen to after grabbing the above mutex, but because I want it to wait for the semaphore then I can end up in a situation where the semaphore is always signaled and thus it doesn't work.

Anyone have a good idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: If this is C#, try this:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4430/Single-Instance-Application-in-C

Comment: Doesn't matter, even if you give me a working example in ML I will still figure it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need inter-process communication, to send a signal to the existing application. For C#, see [IPC Mechanisms in C# - Usage and Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121/ipc-mechanisms-in-c-sharp-usage-and-best-practices).

Answer (score 1):

Cine, I've written a two-Mutex logic. The first one is the "execution lock", while the second is the "monitor lock".
When the first process can't acquire the *monitor lock*, it will exit and release the *execution lock* for the new process.

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, and any feedback will be welcome.

C#:

```
class Program
    {
        private static string processName = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh.mm.ss");
        private static bool exitProcess;

        private static Mutex firstLock
        {
            get
            {
                return new Mutex(false, "stackoverflow.com/questions/11304052/");
            }
        }

        private static Mutex secondLock
        {
            get
            {
                return new Mutex(false, "stackoverflow.com/questions/11304052/ #2");
            }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Process {0} starting", processName));

            exitProcess = false;

            while (true)
            {
                using (firstLock)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Process {0} trying to get #1 mutex", processName));

                    if (!firstLock.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), false))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Process {0} #1 mutex in use, waiting for release", processName));

                        bool killFirstApp = false;

                        while (!killFirstApp)
                        {
                            killFirstApp = LockSecondMutex();
                        }

                        continue;
                    }

                    new Thread(MonitorSecondMutex).Start();

                    RunProgram();

                    firstLock.ReleaseMutex();

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        static void RunProgram()
        {
            while (!exitProcess)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Process {0} running", processName));

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        static void MonitorSecondMutex()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                using (secondLock)
                {
                    if (!secondLock.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), false))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Process {0} lost second mutex. Will now exit.", processName));

                        exitProcess = true;

                        break;
                    }

                    secondLock.ReleaseMutex();
                }

                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        static bool LockSecondMutex()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                using (secondLock)
                {
                    if (!secondLock.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), false))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(5000);

                    secondLock.ReleaseMutex();
                }

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ugh, a spinwait? But otherwise a nice solution

Comment: I tried handling an event with the Mutex, but I don't know if that's possible. It's kind of a spin-wait, but as it does not occurs on the main thread, I thought it could be of some use. Copy the code and give a try, I'd like to see your improvement on this idea =)

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly get this done by requesting access to some limited system-wide resource, such as port.  Your application could bind a socket to a specific port on launch.  If it fails to bind, send a termination signal to the running instance and try again.