# How to exchange data between two process?

Tags: c#, process, .net-3.5, inter-process-communicat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IPC Mechanisms in C# - Usage and Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121/ipc-mechanisms-in-c-sharp-usage-and-best-practices)

I have two diffenent process: `A` and `B`.

The process `A` wants to send to the process `B` some data (array of bytes, strings, structures, etc...). So suppose `A` need to send the following buffer:

```
var buffer = new byte[100].
SendToAnotherProcess(B, buffer);
```

And `B` need to receive this buffer:

```
byte[] buffer;
ReceiveFromAnotherProcess(A, out buffer);
```

What is the easiest solution to do this?

Comment: Google "windows interprocess communication".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Named Pipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx). If it is C# 4.0 and above, you can also use [Memory mapped file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx)

Comment: +1 for the named pipe. Using memory mapped files can be troublesome if not implemented properly.

Answer (score 2):

There's a multitude of options. To name a few low-level IPC mechanisms:

- named pipes
- shared memory
- TCP/IP sockets

Also, there are some higher-level options:

- .NET Remoting
- WCF

Answer (score 0):

One common way is to use files to communicate between the processed.

Each can write to a specific file that the other reads from.

You can use WCF, the registry, network interface, message queues or any other mechanism that lives outside the process.

Comment: The registry as an IPC mechanism. That's pretty dire.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Seen it before...

Comment: Ah, now you mention WCF. That's a bit more like it.

Answer (score 0):

There is some special instrument in .net:

[.Net Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx)