# Windows service does not start WPF application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, console-application

I have an ASP.Net Core application that runs as Windows Service. Its task is to check files on the FTP server when the condition is met is to launch the WPF application.

The application works properly during tests in the debugger. When it is started as a service it starts but does not start WPF.

```
public class AplicationInstance: SingletonExtension<AplicationInstance>
    {

        public SessionOptions FTPSessionOptions { get; set; }
        public string FTPFingerprint { get; set; }

        public List<FileModel> CurrentFiles;
        public List<FileModel> OldFiles;
        public ObservableCollection<FileModel> DifrentFiles;

        private AplicationInstance()
        {
            CurrentFiles = new List<FileModel>();
            OldFiles = new List<FileModel>();
            DifrentFiles = new ObservableCollection<FileModel>();


            StartNewAplicationThread();
            Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
        }


        public Application app { get; set; }
        public void DispatchToApp(Action action)
        {
            app.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
        }
        [STAThread]
        private void StartNewAplicationThread()
        {
            var appthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    app = new Application();
                    app.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;

                    app.Run();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var t = ex.Message; ;
                }
            }));
            appthread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            appthread.Start();
            appthread.Name = "NSP Files -> All File Browser " + DateTime.Now;

        }
    }
```

```
 private static void StartWpfWindows()
        {
            WPFStartModel _newWPFApplication = new WPFStartModel();
            _newWPFApplication.Title = "xxx";
            _newWPFApplication.Files = AplicationInstance.Instance.CurrentFiles;


            AplicationInstance.Instance.DispatchToApp(() =>
            {

                appWindow = new WPFAplication.FileListWindow(_newWPFApplication);
                appWindow.Show();
            });
        }
```

**EDIT** (answer first 2 comments):
The problem occurs in the built version (Release)
I have an additional application that adds a new Windows Service and starts it, all through CMD.

```
 public static async Task<string> ExecuteCommand(string command, int timeMiliseconds = 0)
        {
            try
            {

                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
                    new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

                procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                procStartInfo.Verb = "runas";

                Console.WriteLine(command);
                System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

                proc.Start();

                proc.WaitForExit();

                if (!proc.HasExited)
                {
                    if (timeMiliseconds != 0)
                        await Task.Delay(timeMiliseconds);
                    else
                        await Task.Delay(400);
                }

                string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                {
                    return result;
                }
                else return string.Empty;
            }
            catch (Exception objException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CMD EXCEPTION: " + objException.Message);
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

I use command:

```
                string _tmpCommand = "sc create " + ServiceName + " binPath= \"" + ServicePath + "\"";
//And
                string _tmpCommand = "sc start " + ServiceName;
```

I build app with this command: "dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64"

Comment: Have you tried starting a new Process instead of the way you do in the example?

Comment: Are you installing windows service after building your solution in Release mode or Debug mode?

Comment: Thanks for showing interest. I responded in editing the post.

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? Where do you expect the UI to appear, on which user's desktop? What if there's no logged-in user? Whatever you want to do, a Web site running as a service that pops up forms isn't the way to go

Comment: Possible duplicate [UI for windows service in dot net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067199/ui-for-windows-service-in-dot-net)

Comment: Services do normally not have access to the users desktop

Comment: You should read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services) from Microsoft. Excerpt: `By default, services use a noninteractive window station and cannot interact with the user. However, an interactive service can display a user interface and receive user input.`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I am tired of this problem for 3 days. Unfortunately, I can't create an interactive service. Could you help me?