# Static members behavior with multiple instance of application - C#

Tags: c#, static, static-members

I'm working on my Window Application and i'm using some static members.

```
public class MyParameter
{
    public static string connectionString = "...";
}
```

Now if I install my application on computer and open two instance of same application. Will 'connectionString' common to the two instances?? Or every instance has its connectionString ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The variable static or not is a part of your *application* memory. When you open 2 instances of your *application* you create two *distinct* memory locations in the OS, so there is not any relation between those 2 variables at all.

If you want to create one (relation), you have to look on different IPC (Inter Process Communication) methods available in OS, like:

- [Memory Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997372%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Named Pipes](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/441841/Csharp-Named-Pipes-with-Async)
- [IPC Mechanisms in C# - Usage and Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121/ipc-mechanisms-in-c-sharp-usage-and-best-practices)

Comment: Is there anything similar in Java?

Answer (score 4):

No, Each application instance are isolated from one another using AppDomain. Thus each application instance will run in a seperate AppDomain and cannot access the variables from other domain. To do communicate with different domain we need to use Remoting , WCF Service

Answer (score 3):

Every instance.

Static members are allocated on a per `AppDomain` basis. If you were to spawn a new `AppDomain` from within your current one.. they would be different.