# easily share/access single variable (string) between 2 local running processes

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2013, inter-process-communicat

2 local and running applications:
App #1 periodically (timer1 @30sec) writes "ping" to a shared/"crossprocess" string.
App #2 periodically checks (timer2 @60sec) if shared string == "ping" and overwrites it with "pong".
As timer2 > timer1 App #2 will always receive/read the string as "ping". If not then I can certainly assume that App #1 crashed/hangs and restart it.

I know this can be done really easy with Clipboard...

```
Clipboard.Clear();
Clipboard.SetData("checkthis", "ping");
.
.
.
object clip = Clipboard.GetData("checkthis")
if (clip.ToString() == "ping")
{
    Clipboard.Clear();
    Clipboard.SetData("checkthis", "pong");
}
```

...but I think it is a really bad idea to use Clipboard as the user can easily mess it up.
**Is there an other solution as easy to use as Clipboard?**

Comment: You should use [named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory-mapped files are one approach: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997372(v=vs.100).aspx will do the job.

Named Pipes are another.

An ordinary file work, too. Just have each process put a `FileSystemWatcher` on the file and listen for changes.

Comment: MMF are working, thanks. Although the code from MS is always creating an FilNoFoundException, i used: http://www.shujaat.net/2010/12/interprocess-messaging-using-memory.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this thread in SO will help you solve your problem. Good luck!

[Static members behavior with multiple instance of application - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272544/static-members-behavior-with-multiple-instance-of-application-c-sharp)