# Accessing static members across processes C#

Tags: c#, process, static

Ok, here is the problem. I have a third party c# lib and im kind of writing a tool about it. So there are a few static Containers that i want to monitor from another application but ofcourse i cant reach them in the domain of my app. 
A simple example would be :

```
namespace DefinedInAsembly1
{
     public class Resource
     {
       public static IList<DateTime> DateTimes {get;set;}
     }
}
```

---

```
 namespace DefinedInAssembly2
 {
    class RunningProgram
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         while(true)
         {
          Resource.DateTimes.Add(DateTime.Now); 
          Thread.Sleep(10000);
         }
      }
    }
 }
```

---

```
namespace DefinedInAssembly3
{
 class ToolProgram
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         //Accessing Resource.DateTimes with the values inserted from RunningProgram
         //Any ideas?
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: If you have another process, then there is no magic, the only solution is to use IPC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use *any* of available on host OS IPC (Inter Process Commnuication) tecniques:

- [Memory Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997372%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Named Pipes](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/441841/Csharp-Named-Pipes-with-Async)
- [IPC Mechanisms in C# - Usage and Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121/ipc-mechanisms-in-c-sharp-usage-and-best-practices)

So applications that have to be listened by someone, should expose themselves via one of these, so another application that would like to sniff, or affect the state of them, can communicate with them via these channels.

Comment: About IPC, I think it's worth saying that WCF could really help with communication between 2 .Net processes.

Comment: @ken2k: in the last link (SO answer) there is a reference on WCF too.

Comment: Is there no other way? Can't i use something like reflection or else.Like i said its kind of a tool so i dont wont to touch the "RunningProgram" or "Resource"  @ken2k

Comment: @SimeonDimov No you can't. If there are 2 processes, each process has its own memory space allocated, and you can't share data between them without implementing some IPC mechanism.

Comment: Found my way around.Thank you

Comment: NP method was simple after adjusting for .net 4.5