# how to return value from window to another C#

Tags: c#

I have this code

```
public void BckGrwndWrkrInHst()
{
    var BWLoad = new BackgroundWorker()
    { WorkerReportsProgress = true };
    BWLoad.RunWorkerAsync();
    BWLoad.DoWork += Bwload_DoWork;
    BWLoad.ProgressChanged += Bwload_ProgressChanged;
}
```

and these three methods :

```
private void Bwload_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    LPrgrBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

public void Bwload_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    method(/* dnw what to do */);
}
public void method(string a , string b)
{
    //work to do 
}
```

And on the other window, I have two values a1 and b1.

I want to call the `BckGrwndWrkrInHst()` which calls the other three methods
and I want to return a1 and b1 in  the `method(a1,b1)`. I don't know how to do this

```
(application.current.mainwindow as mainwindow).BckGrwndWrkrHst();
```

Comment: If you are talking about different processes, then [IPC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/56121/1997232) is the way to go.

Comment: As an aside, abbreviating method names is a bad habit to get into.  Methods are generally 'write once, read many', so you should write them for future people, including yourself, to easily read and understand.

Comment: can you show me w to do it please @DarrenYoung

Comment: Google for delegating methods