# How to raise event in one process from another process in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two WPF applications. A application(One process) have grid that have records that have hyper link column. On click of hyper link, application B should be opened(another process) with hyperlink data. I have achieved this by creating process object in application A with arguments property for sending hyper link data. When user click another record in application A, the application should be maximized that is also achieved but how to send the hyperlink data(Another record) to second application( already open process).Please help me one this. My question is how to raise event from process A to process B in C# and how to receive the data to Process B if it is already open.

Comment: How to raise event from one process to another process in C#

Comment: Since both applications are separated you cannot just use the "event" mechanism because their memory space is not shared at all.
You have to look other mechanism like MSMQ (to communicate through queue between different process).

Comment: The term to search for is *interprocess communication*.

Comment: See [IPC mechanism in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121/ipc-mechanisms-in-c-sharp-usage-and-best-practices)

Comment: One set of tools I've personally used for IPC is [NamedPipeServerStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream) and [NamedPipeClientStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream).