# Is anonymous pipe the right choice in this case?

Tags: c#, .net, ipc

I want to do some IPC for process `P` and process `Q` in the local PC. `P` needs notify `Q` with messages, so does `Q`. Now I consider anonymous pipes, which can be used for IPC on local machine. In my case, I can create two pipes in two separate threads, one is for `P` writes to `Q` and `Q` reads from `P`, the other is for `P` reads from `Q` and `Q` writes to `P`. This could work, but I feel it is imperfect.

It could be better, if I can have a message center, `P` and `Q` register event handler for the events they feel interested in, then both `P` and `Q` can write messages (data) to this message center. That is, I hope `P` or `Q` can be notified once some messages received. I'm unclear on which way is best to implement this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IPC Mechanisms in C# - Usage and Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121/ipc-mechanisms-in-c-sharp-usage-and-best-practices)

Comment: @Charlieface maybe I need use the chromium ipc way.